# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Invalidate CloudFront after each deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to manage my PHP Laravel Application. I am also using AWS CloudFront. I need to find a way how to invalidate the CloudFront every time I deploy a new version of the application to Elastic Beanstalk? Ideally I'm looking for some script to put inside the ".ebextensions" folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) to run scripts at certain points of the EB deployment process. You can place a script in the `.platform/hooks/postdeploy` directory which will be run once a new version has been deployed.

If you're running Amazon Linux 2, the AWS CLI will be installed for you, so all you need to do is add the `cloudfront:CreateInvalidation` action to your EB EC2  IAM instance profile, add a `CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID` env var with your CloudFront distribution ID as the value, and then create a script at `.platform/hooks/postdeploy/cloudfront_purge.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID)

/usr/bin/aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id "$CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID" --path "/*"
```